# How to make my buttons disappear onClick (addclass in (click) event handler?)) (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Okay, So The code for my alphabetic buttons in my Hangman game works well,
it shows up on the page in the guessed letter section when clicked and
if the letter is correct it is appended to and replaces the underscore in the right place
 (_ _ _ _) 
My question is:
How can I refactor my handleClick(event)
in a way that when the button is clicked the button disappears 
(so maybe by adding a class, set display:none)

```
 export class Input extends Component {

      handleClick = (event) => {
        if (this.props.guesses.includes(event.target.value)) {
          return this.event.value
        } else {
          return this.props.makeGuess(event.target.value.toLowerCase())
        }
      }
      render() {
        const alphabet = [...'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'];

        return (<div className="containerAlph">
          {alphabet.map((letter, index) => <button className="AlphaBet" key={index} onClick={this.handleClick} value={letter}>{letter}</button>)}
        </div>);
      }

    }
```

Comment: this is for OTP kind of scenario ???

Comment: Add a class that depends on a state value. Then in CSS apply a display: none style to elements with that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.

I am going to use the state to do so instead of adding a CSS class. Basically you will keep track of the buttons available through the `alphabet` array. Each time we click on a button, we will remove that letter from the array and re-render the component.

First of all, I would change your `alphabet` array to be a state property. That way every time you update it, it will be re-rendered and your buttons will disappear accordingly.

So first change, in your render function let us change the `alphabet` to come from the state:

```
const { alphabet } = this.state
```

I declared this in the component's constructor:

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      alphabet : [...'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ']
    }
  }
```

Now... lets deal with the `handleClick` function. We want to pass in which letter we are clicking, and remove that letter from the `alphabet` array.
In the return statement when rendering the buttons, make sure to pass in which letter you are removing in the `handleClick` function.

```
return (<div className="containerAlph">
        {alphabet.map((letter, index) => <button className="AlphaBet" key={index} onClick={() => this.handleClick(letter)} value={letter}>{letter}</button>)}
      </div>);
```

Now for the function itself:
Grab the value of alphabet state, and remove the letter you clicked on from that state.

`this.setState` causes the component to re-render, and now that you removed the letter you clicked on, it won't be displayed anymore.

```
handleClick(letter) {
    const alphabet = [...this.state.alphabet]
    // remove the letter from the state
    const index = alphabet.indexOf(letter)
    if (index > -1) {
      alphabet.splice(index, 1);
    }
    this.setState({ alphabet })
  }
```

Hope that helps.

Here is a working app:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    
    // set the state alphabet as your array so that
    // we can re-render whenever we update it
    this.state = {
      alphabet : [...'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ']
    }
  }
  
  handleClick(letter) {
    const alphabet = [...this.state.alphabet]
    // remove the letter from the state
    const index = alphabet.indexOf(letter)
    if (index > -1) {
      alphabet.splice(index, 1);
    }
    this.setState({ alphabet })
  }
  
  render() {
    const { alphabet } = this.state

    return (<div className="containerAlph">
        {alphabet.map((letter, index) => <button className="AlphaBet" key={index} onClick={() => this.handleClick(letter)} value={letter}>{letter}</button>)}
      </div>);
}

}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Update: as mentioned in the conversation, here is how I think your `handleClick` should be to incorporate the other stuff you would like to happen:

```
handleClick = (event, letter) => {
    // First do the stuff to make the button disappear
    const alphabet = [...this.state.alphabet]
    const index = alphabet.indexOf(letter)
    if (index > -1) {
      alphabet.splice(index, 1);
    }
    this.setState({ alphabet })

    // now do the other stuff
    if (this.props.guesses.includes(event.target.value)) {
        return this.event.value
    } else {
        return this.props.makeGuess(event.target.value.toLowerCase())
    }
 }
```

Now in the render function, we just need to pass in both parameters:

```
render() {
    const { alphabet } = this.state

    return (<div className="containerAlph">
        {alphabet.map((letter, index) => <button className="AlphaBet" key={index} onClick={(event) => this.handleClick(event, letter)} value={letter}>{letter}</button>)}
      </div>);
}
```

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic!
Thing is, 
I have my state in a reducer file (learning redux here)
so how (if you know?)
would I implement this?
do I put it in the initial state :

const initialState = {
  word: '',
  guesses: []
}

Comment: This would be the state of your component. So you don't even need to worry about the redux states, they are completely separate. Or is that not what you are referring to?

Comment: yes, that I understand,
and it works perfectly
but when I use your logic
the buttons disappear,
but now the state of the other components isn't updated
I.e the wrong guesses aren't counting up and the right ones aren't appended to the line (_ _ _ _ )  
that portion of the logic was handled by the
if (this.props.guesses.includes(event.target.value)) {
      return this.event.value
    } else {
      this.props.makeGuess(event.target.value.toLowerCase())
    }

that updated the redux state,

Comment: if that makes any sense

Comment: I also have a Play again button
which fires up a newGame
a new random word is selected 
but the local state in the component is not updated and so the letters that were gone remain invisible.....

const initialState = {
  word: '',
  guesses: []
}


export default(state = initialState, action = {}) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case NEW_GAME:
      return action.payload
    case MAKE_GUESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        guesses: state.guesses.concat(action.payload)
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

Comment: You should be able to just include all that logic in the `handleClick` function completely separately from the component's state. I'll add your old code to the answer in a way that I think it should be handled.

Comment: As for the `Play again` button, I don't know where that is handled, but you can just have something handling it and reset the component's state.